# RollupError: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt3 application running just fine. Now, whenever I build my project to be able to deploy it I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  RollupError: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)                                                                                                                           nitro 5:31:59 PM


1: �PNG
   ^
2:
IHDR�����IDATx�W�cY�څ����i�k�޶L�
                                �c�5��dm��x�����f���U�^���=�<'���2��v��nX�0
                                                                           E�
...                                                                          ��h��v*


 ERROR  Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)                                                                                                                                              5:31:59 PM

  at error (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:337:30)
  at parseError (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:972:9)
  at convertNode (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2057:12)
  at convertProgram (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:965:12)
  at parseAstAsync (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2108:12)
  at async Module.tryParseAsync (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13539:20)
  at async Module.setSource (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13120:35)
  at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17810:13)



 ERROR  Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

I have searched the following questions in QA:

- [Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript) when I use scss in rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921915/unexpected-character-note-that-you-need-plugins-to-import-files-that-are-no)
- [Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911896/error-unexpected-character-note-that-you-need-plugins-to-import-files-that)
- [rollup build scss error.tip: Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72027309/rollup-build-scss-error-tip-error-unexpected-character-note-that-you-need)
- [Vue.js Vite Build Error with <video><source> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70629740/vue-js-vite-build-error-with-videosource-tags)

All of these questions are related to SCSS and neither of them actually shows anything related to my `png`.

Currently I'm only importing a single image into my project in my `app.vue`:

```
<NuxtImg
 class="w-full fixed top-0 z-[-1]"
 src="/images/dark-bg.png"
/>
```

In my `public/` folder I simply have the following structure:

```
- images
-- dark-bg.png
- favicon.ico
```

I have tried removing completely this `dark-bg.png` from my project alongside the `<NuxtImg>` tag but the error still persists.

Here's my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
// @ts-ignore
import type { NuxtPage } from "@nuxt/schema";

// @ts-ignore
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    prerender: {
      autoSubfolderIndex: false
    },
  },
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  hooks: {
    'pages:extend'(pages: NuxtPage[]) {
      pages.push({
        name: 'location',
        path: '/location/:citySlug',
        file: '~/pages/spots/[citySlug].vue'
      })
    }
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.NUXT_API_BASE_URL || 'https://api.sunsetzinho.com/'
    }
  },
  modules: [
    'nuxt-primevue',
    'nuxt3-leaflet',
    'nuxt-icon',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    '@vee-validate/nuxt',
    '@nuxt/image',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],
  primevue: {},
  veeValidate: {
    // disable or enable auto imports
    autoImports: true,
    // Use different names for components
    componentNames: {
      Form: 'VeeForm',
      Field: 'VeeField',
      FieldArray: 'VeeFieldArray',
      ErrorMessage: 'VeeErrorMessage'
    }
  },
  css: [
    'primevue/resources/themes/aura-dark-noir/theme.css',
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '~/assets/css/vendors/leaflet.css'
  ]
})
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.11.3",
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/platform": "^1.3.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "nuxt": "^3.10.0",
    "nuxt-icon": "^0.6.8",
    "nuxt-primevue": "^0.2.2",
    "nuxt3-leaflet": "^1.0.12",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "vue": "^3.4.15",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.3.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "@tiptap/pm": "^2.2.2",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.2.2",
    "@tiptap/vue-3": "^2.2.2",
    "@vee-validate/nuxt": "^4.12.5",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "mitt": "^3.0.1",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "platform": "^1.3.6",
    "primevue": "^3.47.2",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

What seems to be the problem with that error? It's not really that descriptive.

## EDIT

I have the following `png` files in my `node_modules`:

```
$ find node_modules -type f -regex ".*\.png"
node_modules/undici/docs/assets/lifecycle-diagram.png
node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers.png
node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png
node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png
node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png
node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers-2x.png
```

## EDIT 2

It looks like the following file is giving problems `node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png`:

```
$ cat node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png
�PNG

IHDR)i�}1IDATx�҅��@�
s�Ҕ������p�T۝~��N��ܐ7d������
                            ~�_���"cP\�
�W��Aq�4�^  �W�$Aq�C�Q�_�R�Cfd7&�d՚�H͞_i�8�H�n���I���0bG�i(#T!�F1�  2�o�D$G��)��ɸ��*��� /��etԀZ�P��Hu�����e��Q�
                                                                                                                       �-�ʘ"��~���aK,�Y��vG%���
                                                                                                                                                ��Q������t���
                                                                                                                                                             +˜Sd+^�Q�/0&�����MM�<�8���
��c�.� u$G��I�q�}��i�D\ȷ�Dt�~�@���jKe��W�zRB�p�8�|�\Ŕ�$�zR��%)�C9���fR(                                                                                                                ��k̸�$��M
�W@���],WK!����~�Rt��r�H�A˄���P�À�a{�Adٱ�+(
                                            R�g��Z��dG" \��4��b�'|�|&y$�):0"
                                                                            �q!�P�;>�彁_ِ3����L5N��
�h���c�Ƨ��ġaM^�q����#R�t�_�3�8�@bIEND�B`�%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused by the `LMap` from [nuxtjs-leaftlet](https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxt3-leaflet) component. Whenever I added the `LMap` component to my app, it would crash.

The solution was to wrap `LMap` into a `client-only`:

```js
<client-only>
  <LMap ...> </LMap>
</client-only>
```